# extracting data from text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

i'm doing a project and need to extract data from a text file.
the text file looks like this:

```
       XFOIL         Version 6.96

 Calculated polar for: NASA/AMES 63A108 MOD C AIRFOIL                  

 1 1 Reynolds number fixed          Mach number fixed         

 xtrf =   1.000 (top)        1.000 (bottom)  
 Mach =   0.000     Re =     0.100 e 6     Ncrit =   9.000

   alpha    CL        CD       CDp       CM     Top_Xtr  Bot_Xtr
  ------ -------- --------- --------- -------- -------- --------
  -8.000  -0.6796   0.09554   0.09079   0.0206   1.0000   0.1151
  -7.750  -0.7040   0.08853   0.08376   0.0066   1.0000   0.1196
  -7.500  -0.6948   0.08383   0.07912   0.0076   1.0000   0.1227
  -7.250  -0.6828   0.08062   0.07590   0.0083   1.0000   0.1279
  -7.000  -0.6902   0.07401   0.06912   0.0003   1.0000   0.1357
  -6.750  -0.6730   0.07107   0.06625   0.0023   1.0000   0.1410
  -6.500  -0.6686   0.06592   0.06093  -0.0017   1.0000   0.1516
  -6.250  -0.6594   0.06196   0.05674  -0.0043   1.0000   0.1656
  -6.000  -0.6402   0.05873   0.05365  -0.0027   1.0000   0.1722
```

and the data continues.

i need to extract the numbers and some of the text.

i looked over the similar question and i couldent implement anything over this.
help.

thank you very much!

Comment: hi. sorry for the quick followup. the number are arranged in colums under the names above -

Comment: Indent 4 spaces for fixed-width formatting. Please adjust if the indentation is now incorrect.

Comment: What text from the header do you require - the column names?  And once the 7 columns of data begins, does it continue that way until the end of the file or is there a gap followed by more/different data?

Comment: If you use a recent version of matlab, check this: http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html